# Integrating the arithmetic series to get the sum of first $n$ squares?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I only learnt today that series can be differentiated and integrated and I wondered if it is possible to apply the techniques of differential calculus to the finite arithmetic series

$$\sum_{x=0}^n x = n(n+1)/2$$

to obtain the sum of the first $n$ squares:

$$\sum_{x=0}^n x^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Comment: There's a technique called "finite differences" which is a lot like differentiation and can be used for these sorts of problem. There is also a technique for handling such series called "generating functions" which can be used in some such sequences, where the operation really is differentiation. Do you know which technique you were learning about today?

Comment: Oh I haven't been dealing with any particular technique, just differentiating simple power series etc. I will look into those topics though!

Comment: "Simple power series" is technically the notion of generating functions, for what it is worth.

Comment: Note that you can get displayed equations by using double dollar signs instead of single dollar signs. They get centred, and things like fractions and sums with limits look less squashed.

Comment: I tried to show how to do this in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/352793/11619). Admittedly the exposition is not very clear, because that time it was about sixth powers, and I was cutting corners. The idea is to look for a polynomial that will let a proof by induction work. You need to adjust the constant of integration to make it for the next value as well. So it can be done that way, but the finite differences method is more common.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The "generating function" approach to these sorts of problems usually uses that if $$f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_iz^i$$ then $f'(z)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)a_{i+1}z^i$

In addition, we can note that:

$$\frac{1}{1-z}f(z) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty s_i z^i$$ where $s_k=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i$. That is, if we know the power series for $a_i$ we know the power series for the partial sums of $a_i$.

Now, we can start with $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum z^i$ to start getting power series for $f'(z)$ and $f''(z)$:

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = f'(z) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)z^i$$
$$\frac{2}{(1-z)^3} = f''(z)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i+1)(i+2)z^i$$

Now, if $a_i=i$, then $$\sum a_iz^i = f'(z) - f(z) = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$$

Letting $s_k=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i$ we get:

$$\sum s_i z^i = \frac{z}{(1-z)^3} = \frac{z}{2}f''(z) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(i+1)(i+2)}{2} z^{i+1}$$

Equating coefficients, we see that $s_i=\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$, which is the result you wanted.

The general solution can be messy. It is probably easier to first study these sorts of sums in terms of finite differences, rather than power series, but the power series view (aka "generating functions") has a lot of interesting applications in combinatorics.

Answer (score 0):

You might have in mind that $s(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^nx^k$ is such that $s'(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^nkx^{k-1}$ hence $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk=s'(1)$.

Now, $(1-x)s(x)=1-x^{n+1}$ hence $(1-x)s'(x)=s(x)-(n+1)x^{n}$. When $x\to1$, $x=1-z$ with $z\to0$, $x^n=1-nz+o(z)$, $s(x)=s(1)-s'(1)z+o(z)$ and $s(1)=n+1$ hence $zs'(1)=n+1-s'(1)z-(n+1)(1-nz)+o(z)$, that is, $2s'(1)=n(n+1)$.
This indicates that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk=\frac12n(n+1)$.

The same technique allows to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk(k-1)+\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk=s''(1)+s'(1)$ since the second derivative $(1-x)s''(x)=2s'(x)-n(n+1)x^{n-1}$ yields the limited expansion $zs''(1)=2s'(1)-2zs''(1)-n(n+1)(1-(n-1)z)+o(z)$, hence $3s''(1)=n(n+1)(n-1)$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac16n(n+1)(2n+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have, $$f(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n$$

$$\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1} = 1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n$$

Differentiating,

$$\frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(x-1)^2} = 1+2x+3x^2+\cdots+nx^{n-1}$$

Multiplying both sides by $x$

$$\frac{nx^{n+2}-(n+1)x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2} = x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots+nx^{n}$$

Differentiating, *again*

$$\frac{(-2n^2-2n+1)x^{n+1} +n^2x^{n+2} +(n+1)^2x^n-x-1 }{(x-1)^3} = 1+2^2x+3^2x^2+\cdots+n^2x^{n-1}$$

Then [take the limit](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+%28differentiate+%28%28nx%5E%28n%2B2%29-%28n%2B1%29x%5E%28n%2B1%29%2Bx%29%2F%28x-1%29%5E2%29%29+at+x%3D1) at $x\to1$,
and we're done.

**Disclaimer**: This is not at all advisable, and was done just for curiosity. I had to use WA for the differentiation, as I lack the patience

Comment: okay I just noticed this post is ages old.

Comment: @Sabyasashi The fact that the OP accepts no answer to the question they asked does not help.

Comment: wow this is awesome! What was the motivation for working with your $f(x)$?

Comment: @Ovi I apologize for the late reply.

I wanted to create a series with the coefficients as squares of integers, starting with some simple well known series, and after that it was just creativity.